# Import stops copying to table during import in SQL Server Wizard

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, import

I am trying to import a `.csv` as a flat file through the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. Everything seems to go fine until the end. It inadvertently stops copying after about 56k rows (the total row count is about 157k). The table gets created and the rows are filled up to row 56160. I assume this means there is no issue with the data types being brought in and when I look at the original csv, nothing seems out of the ordinary (no super long values or different data types). Could this be a storage issue? Why would it just stop?[image]

Comment: Can you press "Report"? What is written there?

Comment: Export to .xls has the limit, try to export to .xlsx

Comment: @ScrappyCoco, yep. forgot about that. It shows row number and some truncation issues. I fixed them and reimported and that fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @gwydion93 Thank you for sharing your solution. You may want to `Answer` your own question and `Mark` it as an answer. Generally readers look for a green check mark to see if question has a solution. It will help other readers, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was trying to import as an .xls. Simply save the document (if its not already in that format) to an .xlsx (workbook) and import it that way. As always, check the previewer for truncation issues in the wizard before finalizing.